# LocalBroadcast Receiver in Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am noob in android. I noticed first time this term `LocalBroadcastReceiver` in Android. Anyone know where `LocalBroadcastReceiver` can be used in android ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LocalBroadCastReceiver` is used to receive the application level broadcasts , for using it u have to use `LocalBroadcastManager`, it is generally used if you dont want to leak your data outside the app.

for details refer this :- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html

consider a scenario in which you are downloading any file, when your download is complete you want to notify it to your application , and in this case you dont need to send a system level broadcast.

you will send broadcast in this way :-

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast("downloadComplete");
```

and receive it in this way :-

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
        mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter("downloadComplete"));
```

where mMessageReceiver is your receiver defined dynamically

Comment: Any example do you know ?

Comment: Downloading file where in service or other ??? and when download complete then notify where ??

Comment: yeah in service or any other thread , you have to create a broadcast receiver and register it in your activity !!

Comment: Suppose downloading is going on in service then user has exit then app then who will get message that was broadcast by local broadcast receiver

Answer (score 1):

It is the same general idea as a normal broadcast in android. You send out an Intent from any place within you app and the receiver registered to this Intent is dealing with receiving it.

Local just means, the broadcast is only send within your app and not to the entire android system. -> more private and more efficient